# Borrow free space on a partition to create another partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I using windows 7. There is a partition (**Z:**) on my disk from which I want to borrow 15 GB to create an unallocated partition on which I'll install a second Linux OS.
Below is a picture of diskmgmt to illustrate what I mean

[image: Image of my hard drive partitions]

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 offers that built-in, although there are third-party software to do with more options. Here is how to do it directly in the Disk Management:

- Right click on the highlighted NTFS volume and the popup menu which appears will have a menu to *Shrink*.
- Click on *Shrink* and wait for a while as it calculates how much space is available.
- You can choose a lower shrinking about and press OK.

After a few minutes you will have a smaller Z: Drive and you can create a new partition with the available space. It looks like you are at your limit for Primary, so you will probably only be able to create and Extended partition.

Comment: Hey I just complete the steps.  The result is that I have a "Free space" partition now. How can I make it "unallocated" so that I can instal my OS on it ?

Comment: @KurtMiller - Great. In that case, I gave you one step too many! 2 options: (1) Delete the partition you created in the empty space, or (2) install the OS and during the installer tell it to use (and reformat that partition, if it was already). Linux distributions and even Windows can do this.